# Does Firebug have something built-in to disable all javascript for a site/page?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Does Firebug have something built-in to disable all javascript for a site/page?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not that I know of. But you can use the [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) or [noscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722)  addons to do that.

Comment: that's a stupid statement. no one "should" be using that- there's no reason.

Comment: @Greg NoScript is good because you can enable/disable individual JavaScript files. Web developer toolbar is all-or-nothing.

Comment: It's a small hack, but nevertheless great answer! No-Script is good!

Answer (score 4):

In firefox 4 you can just disable javascript in the content tab of the options dialog.

Just uncheck "Enable Javascript".

Answer (score 3):

I would look at noscript. Also the firebug folks (john barton I think is the guy's name) are  very responsive so if you want a feature post it on the google group or bug/enhancement tracker. I don't think it currently has this feature, but check out the 1.4 branch (currently in Alpha), it might (no idea) contain something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firefox add-on the [Web Developer Toolkit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to specifically use Firebug (and not noscript), Firebug has a built debugger called Code Stepper which is perfect for what you are trying to accomplish.

Here is an article which explains how to utilise the debug features to control the flow of JavaScript.

http://fixunix.com/mozilla/407230-how-write-simple-debugger-code-stepper-will-just-allownormal-steps-without-other-fancy-features.html